# How do I "force" pixel-registered grid for plotting x,y,z,s on 3d surface?

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, plot

I want to plot a small, say 4x4 array on a plane in 3d. I have a 2d array **s** which I preview with `plt.imshow` and get a correct 4x4 cell image. However, when I plot **s** onto a **x, y, z** plane (**x, y,** and **z** are each a 4x4 array) I get a resampled(?) 3x3 cell image mapped onto the plane. Is there an easy way (there probably is...) to force `plot_surface` to treat the data points as pixel-registered with a known pixel size (dx,dy,dz) so that the data is plotted as a 4x4 cell image?

Here is a short and simple code to illustrate my problem:

```
s = np.random.rand(4,4)
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(s, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image: 4x4 array with imshow]

```
x = np.array([1,1,1,1])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
z = y.T

xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zi = z*np.ones((4,4))

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
color = plt.cm.jet(s)

ax.plot_surface(xi, yi, zi,
                rstride=1, cstride=1,
                facecolors=color, shade=False,
                vmin=s.min(), vmax=s.max())
```

[image: 4x4 array resampled onto a 3x3 representation]

Any suggestions?

Comment: `zi = z*np.ones((5,5))` out of curiosity, what would that do? and what is `s` in this scenario?

Comment: `s` is some physical property. making `zi` 5x5 is not enough since `xi`, `yi`, `zi`, and `s` must have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found to work for me is to calculate the vertices of the polygon around each data point using dx, dy, dz:

```
vx = [x-0.5*dx, x+0.5*dx, x+0.5*dx, x-0.5*dx]
vy = [y-0.5*dy, y+0.5*dy, y+0.5*dy, y-0.5*dy]
vz = [z-0.5*dz, z-0.5*dz, z+0.5*dz, z+0.5*dz]
```

then use `Poly3DCollection` from `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d` to draw the polygon.

I hope this helps someone else as-well.

Shahar